# Hexadecimal to signed 32-bit conversion

Tags: java, android, hex, decimal

i want to convert hexadecimal value to a signed decimal number.like FFFFFB2E to -1234.Is there any method to do this in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Long.parseLong` by passing 16 as radix of the number that you are entering as below:

```
long myHexNumber = Long.parseLong("FFFFFB2E", 16);
int number = (int)myHexNumber;
System.out.println(number);
```

Comment: It is not giving the negative value. it gives 4294966062

Comment: Why would you expect negative number? Do you need to convert this to int? See my edited answer its giving -1234 as you expected.

Comment: I am getting the Hexvalues from RFDuino to my android device, and needed to convert this in decimal so i need the exact values send from RFDiuno to Decimal thats why needs negative. But Your Edited answer says cannot cast from long to int. What should i do now.
Thanks for your reply

Comment: Did you do exactly as above? Its working for me so should work for you as well. Please paste the trace as well.

Comment: I am doing this. But it shows error at 2nd line
 Long outputDecimal = Long.parseLong("4D2", 16);
  int number = (int)outputDecimal;

Comment: See i used primitive long and not wrapper Long. So use primitive long.

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer.parseInt(String, int), per [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)):

```
Parses the string argument as a signed integer in the radix specified by the second argument. The characters in the string must all be digits of the specified radix (as determined by whether Character.digit(char, int) returns a nonnegative value), except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned.
An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:

The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.
Examples:

 parseInt("0", 10) returns 0
 parseInt("473", 10) returns 473
 parseInt("+42", 10) returns 42
 parseInt("-0", 10) returns 0
 parseInt("-FF", 16) returns -255
 parseInt("1100110", 2) returns 102
 parseInt("2147483647", 10) returns 2147483647
 parseInt("-2147483648", 10) returns -2147483648
 parseInt("2147483648", 10) throws a NumberFormatException
 parseInt("99", 8) throws a NumberFormatException
 parseInt("Kona", 10) throws a NumberFormatException
 parseInt("Kona", 27) returns 411787
```

Comment: OP's number wont fit in the range of int and hence OP would get NumberFormatException if OP uses parseInt method.